# How to display sinatra error and other variables in minitest output

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, sinatra, minitest

I am testing and coding a sinatra app using minitest. Currently, I use last_response.status to see what happened with the request by:

```
assert last_response.ok?, "Status 200 expected but was #{last_response.status}."
```

which displays errors like "Status 200 expected but was 500." but I would like to display the sinatra.error in Rack ENV, like:

```
sinatra.error #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)>
```

so that I don't have to start the app and check it on the browser. I tried this code:

```
assert last_response.ok?, "#{last_response.error}."
```

but it threw a "private method `error' called for #" error.

**How can I display the values of the variables in sinatra error output?**

Comment: Try `last_response.send(:error)`.

Comment: Throws a no method error, and also I couldn't find send method in [Rack Documentation](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/). Where did you find it?

Comment: It's not a Rack method. It's `Object#send`. You can access private methods using that. You could try `Object#__send__` also if `send` has been undefined.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send

Comment: It throws a "tried to create Proc object without a block" error. I didn't learn procs yet, though I tried. Would you mind to guide me on procs in ruby, if that's the problem. I mean, where can I learn procs thoroughly?

Comment: @Casper you don't need to use #send. Just use #errors. See my answer below.

Comment: @three - Yeah I just noticed that looking at the source too. That's good...much better solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `puts last_response.errors` to show the Rack error messages for the last response.

Comment: Many thanks, now I use `assert last_response.ok?, "Status 200 expected but was #{last_response.status}.\n#{last_response.errors.split("\n").first}"` which shows me in a single line, what specifically caused the 500 error.

Comment: why? I use errors solely for debugging stupid errors. I don't expect them and use them in my usual test code.

Comment: Right, the same here. But now I am having a problem with user create action and sinatra complains with an ArgumentError, which is a stupid error, I think. And I would like to be able to check it (2 for 3 or 1 for 3 etc..) within the tests, without opening the browser. Anyways, this tought me that I should open my eyes and my mind once again. I mean, I tried last_response.error but not errors after all. So thank you again.